# Error caused by change of namespace?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, namespaces

I decided to change title of my program. I changed the project name but namespace didn't change. In fact, when I try to change all namespaces manually it causes errors causing my variables to go haywire!

How can I change namespaces in my all project files with out causing any problems?

Example. Change this:

```
namespace Store_Passwords_and_Serial_Codes
{
}
```

Into this:

```
namespace Password_Manager
{
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the built-in refactoring support in Visual Studio: Right-click the namespace in question and select `Refactor..|Rename`. This will propagate the changes everywhere it's needed.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you right click on the namespace and select Refactor->Rename in VS2010?

Comment: I did not know I could do that.